# Incorrect item key : Zabbix Monitoring trigger

Tags: zabbix

I want to set Zabbix monitoring agent for one of my test website. I have already set web-scenario. I am going to set triggers for the website but received an error of **Incorrect Item key**. How can I set trigger?

> Incorrect item key "web.test.rspcode[test.com.test.com]"provided for
>   trigger expresssion on "NickProject"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use web scenario and step names in the item key parameters. You currently have provided only one parameter there, `test.com.test.com`. Two options:

- look up scenario and step names, reproduce them exactly
- use the item selector in the other trigger properties tab and let it fill in the item key for you

The second option is much easier.